# Eclipse Package Explorer: Hide part of long package names?

Tags: eclipse

I've been searching for a "problem" that have annoyed me for a while (but without any luck).

I am developing an Android application with the rather long package name `com.kennethbrodersen.simplecaster`.

This project contains a number of subpackages. The problem is that all these packages are shown with the full package identifier in the package explorer. The result is that this view has to be very wide or that I have to scroll horizontally to actually view the interesting part of the name. The problem is very clearly visible on the screenshot below.

Do any of you know of a way to "hide" parts of the identifier (in this case `com.kennethbrodersen.simplecaster`)?

[image: Eclipse Package Explorer]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can configure package name abbreviations in Helios (3.6) or later. Go to **Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance** to set up abbreviation rules.

For example, `com.kennethbrodersen.simplepod` could be configured to be displayed as `{KBsimple}` with the rule `com.kennethbrodersen.simplepod={KBsimple}`.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. Sometimes the good stuff is hidden away :-)

Comment: IS there a way for the sub directories within the packages to be shortened similar to what was accomplished here?  THanks!

Comment: @GelSisaed Please ask a separate question so you get more people looking at it. By asking in a comment, only one person is going to see this, and that person hasn't looked at this in 7 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install FeatureIDE plugin, which will show only short (package)name.